# Cannot use linux fonts in emacs under Bash for Windows

Tags: emacs, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running bashforwindows, and have install emacs natively (*not* emacs for windows) following the awesome instructions given by Luke Lee to install from source here: [How to use X Windows with Emacs on Windows 10 Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39182483/how-to-use-x-windows-with-emacs-on-windows-10-bash)

I can run emacs fine from bash, using MobaXTerm as the xserver. However, I cannot get emacs to see any of my linux fonts (or windows fonts, for that matter).

From my shell, I can run `fc-list` and get a list that includes things like consola and Inconsolata (which is what I want):

```
[~]$ fc-list
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf: DejaVu Serif:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf: DejaVu Sans Mono:style=Book
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf: DejaVu Sans:style=Book
/home/hal/.local/share/fonts/consolaz.ttf: Consolas:style=Bold Italic
/home/hal/.local/share/fonts/Inconsolata-Bold.ttf: Inconsolata:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf: DejaVu Sans:style=Bold
/home/hal/.local/share/fonts/consolai.ttf: Consolas:style=Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf: DejaVu Sans Mono:style=Bold
/home/hal/.local/share/fonts/Inconsolata-Regular.ttf: Inconsolata:style=Regular
/home/hal/.local/share/fonts/consolab.ttf: Consolas:style=Bold
/home/hal/.local/share/fonts/consola.ttf: Consolas:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/inconsolata/Inconsolata.otf: Inconsolata:style=Medium
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSerif.ttf: DejaVu Serif:style=Book
```

However, emacs cannot see these. If I run emacs from that shell, and then from emacs run `(print (font-family-list))`, I get:

```
("courier" "helvetica" "new century schoolbook" "times" "utopia"
"lucida" "lucidabright" "lucidatypewriter" "fixed" "nil" "clearlyu
alternate glyphs" "clearlyu arabic extra" "clearlyu arabic" "clearlyu
devanagari" "clearlyu devangari extra" "clearlyu ligature" "clearlyu
pua" "clean" "fixed" "open look cursor" "open look glyph" "courier"
"helvetica" "new century schoolbook" "times" "utopia" "lucida"
"lucidabright" "lucidatypewriter" "fixed" "nil" "clearlyu alternate
glyphs" "clearlyu arabic extra" "clearlyu arabic" "clearlyu
devanagari" "clearlyu devangari extra" "clearlyu ligature" "clearlyu
pua" "clean" "fixed" "open look cursor" "open look glyph" "fixed")
```

which does not contain any of fonts I want.

How can I get emacs to see the fonts that are available, or otherwise find some other way of installing them?

Answer (score 0):

Get an emacs version which is compiled with fontconfig support, not one that only uses the (ugly, deprecated limited) X core fonts subsystem

Comment: Thanks! I tried rebuilding from scratch with fontconfig support, but it doesn't seem to help. I first apt installed fontconfig and libxft, and emacs configure found them:

checking for fontconfig >= 2.2.0... yes CFLAGS='-I/usr/include/freetype2' LIBS='-lfontconfig -lfreetype'
checking for xft >= 0.13.0... yes CFLAGS='-I/usr/include/freetype2' LIBS='-lXft'

I rebuilt emacs and ran, but get the same list of fonts when I do (print (font-family-list)).